# Varying run time of an OpenMP parallel region

Tags: c, openmp

Whenever I run this code it shows me different run-time took by the parallel section. I tried with a constant number of threads according to my core but still the effort is futile. The program is to calculate the value of pi. Compiled with `gcc -fopenmp`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

static long num_steps = 100000; double step;
//double omp_get_wtime(void);

int main (){
      int i;
      double x,pi,max_threads,start,time;
      double sum=0.0;
      step = 1.0/(double) num_steps;
    //omp_set_num_threads(4);       
      omp_get_max_threads();
      start=omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel
   {

    #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum) schedule(static) private(x) //reduction to get local copy
            for (i=0;i<num_steps;i++){
            x=(i+0.5)*step;
            sum += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
            }
    //max_threads=omp_get_max_threads();
    }
time=omp_get_wtime()-start;
pi=step*sum;
printf("pi=(%f)\t run_time(%f)\n",pi,time);//,max_threads);
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The title of your question is very generic and in no way reflects the actual problem. Please take some time and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help section.

Comment: For consistent run times, a typical requirement is to pin threads and avoid competition from other tasks. If you are doing a simple sum reduction and preventing simd optimization, the task isn't very meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The code runs only a few milliseconds (on my system 2-6 ms), the time is being dominated overhead e.g. for thread creation. The serial version runs <1 ms. It is normal for such short execution times to be very variable as it depends on the current state of the system, e.g. there is some 'warmup needed'.

In this case, just increase `num_steps` to get meaningful stable results. E.g. with `num_steps = 1000000000`, 10 executions are all between 4.332 and 4.399 seconds on my system.

Generally, if you do performance measurements, you should compile with the `-O3` flag.